# How do I get rid of the ugly div/0 error in sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm having trouble finding a way to get rid of the div/0 error for a formula.

The formula is =if(J45="","",(D45/J45)*100).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the IFERROR formula. You can choose a value to be shown in case your formula goes wrong. In that case, you are trying to divide by 0. You could use:

=IFERROR((D45/J45)*100, "")